# Unrecognized selector sent to instance, Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, uigesturerecognizer, uipageviewcontroller

I have a swipe view page created with 2 view controller (view controller and pageItemController) and 1 pageViewController as shown in screenshot.

[image]

There are 4 pics in my swipe page and its an array. so my swipe page includes 4 pages.
The thing I want is to go to a new page when I click on each image in my swipe view. I have added UIgestureRecognizer in my imageView in pageItemController and used this code in pageItemController:

```
import UIKit
class PageItemController: UIViewController {
var itemIndex = Int!()
var imageName: String = "" {

    didSet {

        if let imageView = contentImageView {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }

    }
}

@IBOutlet var contentImageView: UIImageView?



@IBOutlet weak var gameLevel: UIImageView!



func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
    let targetImageIndex =  itemIndex! as Int
    let gameLevel = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameLevelPack") as! GameLevel
    let gameLevelPack2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameLevelPack2") as! GameLevelPack2
    let gameLevelPack3 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameLevelPack3") as! GameLevelPack3
    let gamelevelPack4 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameLevelPack4") as! GameLevelPack4


    switch (targetImageIndex) {
    case 0:
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameLevel, animated: true)
        break;
    case 1:
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameLevelPack2, animated: true)
        break;
    case 2:
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameLevelPack3, animated: true)
        break;
    case 3:
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gamelevelPack4, animated: true)
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor (red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0)


    let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action:Selector("imageTapped:"))
    contentImageView!.userInteractionEnabled = true
    contentImageView!.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    contentImageView!.image =  UIImage(named: imageName)
}
}
```

And I have used this code in viewController:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

private var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

private let contentImages = ["pack1.png",
                             "pack2.png",
                             "pack3.png",
                             "pack4.png"];


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()
}

private func createPageViewController() {

    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as! UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self

    if contentImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as? [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

private func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor (red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0)
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor (red: 100, green: 100, blue: 100, alpha: 0)
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
    }

    return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = viewController as! PageItemController

    if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
        return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
    }

    return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as! PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = contentImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
    }

    return nil
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return contentImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}
}
```

with these codes i get no action when i click on swipe image.
Please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Move the `imageTapped:` method out of the `gameLevel:` method

Comment: i have moved this section out of gameLevel: method, but it isn't work.func imageTapped(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
            let targetImageIndex =  itemIndex! as Int
            
            let gameLevel = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameLevelPack") as! GameLevel

        switch (targetImageIndex) {
        case 0:
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(gameLevel, animated: true)
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37227073/edit) with your updated code – when you say it's still not working, do you mean you're still getting an "Unrecognized selector sent to instance" error?

Comment: hi, i updated my question. i don't get this error anymore, but when i run the app and click on the swipe image, i get no action.